# Why is the size of struct Player is increased by 7 bytes?

Tags: c++

I want to know the reason of increasing the size of struct Player from `25` to `32` bytes. I know using `#pragma pack(push,1)` to strict padding and `#pragma pack(pop)` to release padding of struct but I want to know why even this behavior is occurred, what secrets are behind it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

struct player
{
    char name [13];
    int age;
    double score;
};
int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(player) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

OutPut: 32

Comment: `int`: 4-byte allignment, add 3-byte padding before that `double`: 8-byte allignment, add 4-byte padding before that

Comment: This padding is done to make the stroke more efficient to work with.

Comment: If you want to have a small yet computationally inefficient struct, look into `#pragma pack`

Comment: You can also often get a smaller structure by arranging the variables in the structure to reduce the need for padding.

Comment: OT:  Prefer to use `std::string` for text instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow or underflow.  They can become exciting when there is no terminating nul character.

Comment: Let's say your processor has 32-bit integers.  It's defined to fetch 32-bits at a time.  If the `int` is on a 32-bit aligned boundary, the processor only has to make one fetch.  Any other boundary and the processor may need to make multiple fetches to build a 32-bit integer.  Some processors can only access ints on 32-bit boundaries, otherwise they issue faults.

Comment: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/119123/995714)

Comment: you should almost always arrange struct members from large to small to minimize the padding. You're doing the reverse thing in this case